# Как указать очерёдность событий не через setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я получаю изображение, а затем пытаюсь получить его ширину:

```
$('.tech').append("<img src='/upload/" + data['name'] + "' class='" + data['id'] + " toimg'><p class='psize'></p></div>");
$('.psize').append($('.' + data['id']).get(0).naturalWidth);
```

Но по каким-то причинам я получаю ответ "0". Я так предполагаю, это связано с тем, что изображение ещё не успело создаться, а я уже пытаюсь получить его ширину. Если я установлю setTimeout, то всё будет работать, но это не самый красивый метод, так как за отведённое мной время изображение может не успеть подгрузиться и я опять получу "0". Опять же я теряю во времени, если изображение уже подгрузилось, а я жду непонятно чего.

Подскажите, как указать очерёдность событий, чтобы в начале выполнился append в .tech, а затем append в .psize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.tech').append("<div class='imgwrap'><img src='/upload/" + data['name'] + "' class='" + data['id'] + " toimg'></div><p class='psize'></p>");

$('.' + data['id']).on('load', function(){
    $('.psize').append($(this).get(0).naturalWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded()
.always(function (instance) {
    console.log('all images loaded');
    ---- код сюда -----
});
```

Если проблема в том что изображение еще не погрузилось то существует плагин [imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)

Comment: А если бы дело было не в изображении? Разве в jquery нельзя указать порядок выполнения? У меня есть некоторые сомнения по поводу того, что дело в загрузки изображения, но если уменьшать setTimeout то в какой-то момент скрипт будет выполняться неверно.

Comment: @firebear Ваши эксперименты должны были убедить Вас, что дело именно в асинхронной загрузке изображений.